# how much powerful is calculus of variations than differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

i want to know what things can be built or modelled with variational principles that couldnt or would be very hard to do with ODES.
also much harder is to learn one than the other.

Comment: Many PDE problems can be derived from [variational principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). PDE problems are not ODES...

Comment: Actually, any PDE is an ODE, really just a matter of writing it properly. Simply a variational principle is something different and you need to study them to have a real feeling for the differences.